# Parse text and return list of unmatched brackets in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, stack

I need to parse some text and determine which brackets are unclosed and return a list of brackets that will close them, e.g.

If this is the string that is inputted:

```
({([])
```

Then the function should return a list of brackets to close the sets that have been unmatched:

```
['}', ')']
```

essentially closing off the unmatched sets.

This is the code I have currently:

```
def evaluate(str):
stack = []
missing = []
pushChars, popChars = "({[", ")}]"
for c in str:
    if c in popChars:
        matching = pushChars[popChars.index(c)]
        if not len(stack) or stack[len(stack) - 1] != matching:
            missing.append(c)
        else:
            stack.pop()
        continue
    if c in pushChars:
        stack.append(c)
return missing
```

Comment: But what if you have a wrong bracket sequence like `'({[}'`?

Comment: I would say (for the application this is being used for) it should return an empty list

Comment: I added solution with raising exception in such case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class to parse pairs of text, and if no closing values are found, the invalid character can be appended to a list of characters that are unclosed:

```
class Parse:
  def __init__(self, _str, _to_find = None):
    self.brackets = _str
    self.converter = {'(':')', '[':']', '{':'}', ')':'(', ']':'[', '}':'{'}
    self.search_for = _to_find
    self.flagged = []
    self.parse()
  def parse(self):
    _current = next(self.brackets, None)
    if _current is None and self.search_for is not None:
      self.flagged.append(self.search_for)
    elif _current is not None:
      if _current != self.search_for:
        _result = Parse(self.brackets, self.converter[_current])
        self.flagged.extend(_result.flagged)
        self.brackets = _result.brackets
        self.parse()


p = Parse(iter('({([])'))
print(p.flagged)
```

Output:

```
['}', ')']
```

Note, however, if a valid sequence has been found, `flagged` will be an empty list (`[]`):

```
p = Parse(iter('{{()}}'))
print(p.flagged)
```

Output:

```
[]
```

Comment: So if the bracket sequence is invalid (addressed in comment above) it will be in the flagged list?

Comment: @Antidisestablishmentarianism Only the characters without a closing equivalent are added to the list (as in your desired output).

Comment: Oh I see. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
def evaluate(s):
    stack = []
    result = []
    braces = {'(': ')', '{': '}', '[': ']'}

    for x in s:
        if x in braces.keys():
            stack.append(x)
        elif x == braces[stack[-1]]:
            stack.pop()
        else:
            raise Exception('Non-valid bracket sequence')

    while stack:
        result.append(braces[stack.pop()])

    return result

print(evaluate('({([])'))
```

**Output**:

```
['}', ')']
```